# How to assign the value of a field to another in a single mongo Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Suppose you have a mongo record :

```
{
    _id : 1234,
    x: 12,
    y: 34
}
```

I need a query that will update an particular _id in such a way that

```
x = y;//assign the value of y to x
y = new Date().getTime();//assign current time to y
```

for a particular _id.currently I am reading the id modifying the entity and updating it.Is this possible to do it in a single query? what would be it's equivalent using Mongoose

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that unless you use the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator. But you should avoid doing this  because using `$where` may cause a drop of performance as mentioned in the [documentation](http://Considerations):

> $where evaluates JavaScript and cannot take advantage of indexes. Therefore, query performance improves when you express your query using the standard MongoDB operators (e.g., $gt, $in).

```
db.collection.update({ '$where':  function() { return this.x === this.y }}, 
    {'$set': { 'y': new Date().getTime() }}
)
```

The best way is to run two queries like you did. One to retrieve the `_id` value and the other to update your documents.

You can't assign `y`'s value to `x` and `new Date().getTime()` to `y` using a single MongoDB query. You need to first retrieve `y` value using the `.findOne()` method and then use another query to update the document.

```
var y = db.collection.findOne({ '_id': <given ObjectId()> }, 
    { 'y': 1, '_id': 0 } 
)['y'];

db.collection.update( { '_id': <given ObjectId()> }, 
    { '$set': { 'x': y, 'y': new Date().getTime() } } 
)
```